# how to count no of specific symbol in a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with a row with the data like `'/2323/3235/4545/222/'` how can i count the number of / in every row using mysql only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [quick search](http://www.google.com) came up with this:

```
SELECT LENGTH('/2323/3235/4545/222/') - LENGTH(REPLACE('/2323/3235/4545/222/','/','')) ... etc;
```

Answer (score 3):

[link](http://pisceansheart.wordpress.com/2008/04/15/count-occurrence-of-character-in-a-string-using-mysql/)

```
SELECT LENGTH('/2323/3235/4545/222/') - LENGTH(REPLACE('/2323/3235/4545/222/', '/', '')) AS `occurrences`
```